# wp-scripts start build hangs

Tags: block-editor

I am trying the create-block part as in https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/

But the 'wp-scripts start' command hangs and does not come out.

I am using the latest Wordpress locally. and trying the above.

```
~/WP/gutenpride$ npm run start 

> gutenpride@0.1.0 start /home/user/WP/gutenpride
> wp-scripts start

assets by chunk 17.6 KiB (name: index)
  asset index.js 16.4 KiB [emitted] (name: index) 1 related asset
  asset index.css 1.03 KiB [emitted] (name: index) 1 related asset
  asset index.asset.php 145 bytes [emitted] (name: index)
asset fonts/gilbert-color.02d3d364.otf 612 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: assets/gilbert-color.otf] (auxiliary name: index)
asset ./style-index.css 1.09 KiB [emitted] (name: ./style-index) (id hint: style) 1 related asset
asset block.json 656 bytes [emitted] [from: src/block.json] [copied]
Entrypoint index 18.7 KiB (625 KiB) = ./style-index.css 1.09 KiB index.css 1.03 KiB index.js 16.4 KiB index.asset.php 145 bytes 4 auxiliary assets
runtime modules 5.6 KiB 16 modules
orphan modules 6.42 KiB (javascript) 612 KiB (asset) [orphan] 6 modules
built modules 4.41 KiB (javascript) 746 bytes (css/mini-extract) [built]
  javascript modules 3.86 KiB
    cacheable modules 3.7 KiB
      modules by path ./src/*.js 3.6 KiB 3 modules
      modules by path ./src/*.scss 100 bytes 2 modules
    external ["wp","blocks"] 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    external ["wp","element"] 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    external ["wp","components"] 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    external ["wp","blockEditor"] 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css modules 746 bytes
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[3]!./src/style.scss 444 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[3]!./src/editor.scss 302 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/block.json 562 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 6782 ms
```

Additionally,
When I try to create build,it comes out with warnings.

```
WP/gutenpride$ npm run build

> gutenpride@0.1.0 build /home/user/WP/gutenpride
> wp-scripts build

assets by chunk 1.87 KiB (name: index)
  asset index.js 1.59 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: index)
  asset index.asset.php 145 bytes [emitted] (name: index)
  asset index.css 140 bytes [emitted] (name: index)
asset fonts/gilbert-color.02d3d364.otf 612 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: assets/gilbert-color.otf] [big]
asset block.json 656 bytes [emitted] [from: src/block.json] [copied]
asset ./style-index.css 170 bytes [emitted] (name: ./style-index) (id hint: style)
Entrypoint index 2.04 KiB = ./style-index.css 170 bytes index.css 140 bytes index.js 1.59 KiB index.asset.php 145 bytes
orphan modules 7.59 KiB (javascript) 612 KiB (asset) 2.09 KiB (runtime) [orphan] 25 modules
runtime modules 2.63 KiB 3 modules
built modules 4.31 KiB (javascript) 387 bytes (css/mini-extract) [built]
  ./src/index.js + 7 modules 4.31 KiB [not cacheable] [built] [code generated]
  css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[3]!./src/style.scss 248 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[3]!./src/editor.scss 139 bytes [built] [code generated]

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  fonts/gilbert-color.02d3d364.otf (612 KiB)

WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

webpack 5.74.0 compiled with 2 warnings in 1489 ms
```

My purpose is to build a plugin. Ultimately I should be able to upload the plugin into my local environment.

Any help would be appreciated!

--Shwetha

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is hanging. It's just waiting for a change so that it can automatically build again. That's what [`start`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/#start) does. If you just want to run a build once use [`build`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/#build).

The warnings in your second example are self explanatory: You're using a font asset that is very large and exceeds the recommended maximum size. The second warning is just a summary, and is repeating the same information. Looking at the font in question I can see why it's so large, so you'll just need to decide whether you want to make that trade-off.

Comment: Thank you. It has to do with webpack assetsize